# How can I add InputScope property to my custom passwordBox in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, textbox, windows-runtime, passwordbox, inputscope

I have a custom control is named WatermarkPasswordBox and I want to add InputScope property for using numeric virtual keyboard in WinRT, Win8. But it's base class is not Textbox, it's base class is Control. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I submitted [feedback](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579/suggestions/4433511) for Microsoft to review.  Please vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you could [add an owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754002.aspx) to the `InputScopeProperty`.  But, of course, we're not using WPF here.  Even if that were available, I'm not sure it alone would solve your problem anyway.

To answer your question:

1. Define your own `InputScopeProperty` on your custom `PasswordBox`.
2. Insert a `TextBox` into your custom control's control template.
3. Use a `TemplateBinding` to bind the `TextBox`'s `InputScope` to your custom `InputScope`.

What's preventing you from deriving from `PasswordBox`?  Your custom `PasswordBox` should serve its single, specific purpose so this is something to consider.